# add individual amount of buttons to cell programmatically

Tags: ios, swift

I want to build the following programmatically: 
[image]

but I want to add the custom buttons programmatically. Here I have no idea, how the tell the buttons to respect the space between them and how to resize the height of the cell if the next button didn't fits into the same "row".

i tried with constraints:

```
import Material

class ChipButton: Button {
    override func prepare() {
        super.prepare()

        cornerRadiusPreset      = .cornerRadius5
        backgroundColor         = UIColor.lightGray
        titleColor              = Color.darkText.primary
        pulseAnimation          = .none
        contentEdgeInsets       = EdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 12, bottom: 0, right: 12)
        isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        titleLabel?.font        = RobotoFont.regular
        isOpaque                = true

        let constraintTop       = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: superview, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 4)
        let constraintLeading   = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: superview, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 4)

        superview?.addConstraint(constraintTop)
        superview?.addConstraint(constraintLeading)
    }
}
```

and I add the buttons like the following:

```
for tag in item.tags {
    let chip = ChipButton()
    chip.title  = tag.text

    cell!.layout(chip).edges(top: 4, left: 4, bottom: 4, right: 4)
}
```

but the declaration of constrainTop and constrainLeading throws an error and without the constraints the buttons r on top of each other the and the size of the buttons r false.

Comment: It looks like you're giving all the buttons the same top and leading constraint related to the `superview`. That would lead to them all being on top of each other. You will need to change the constraints to be related to the last added button I believe.

Comment: but if you know where you want to put them, and you're working out all of the spacing anyway - then you don't need constraints, and you can just place them with the correct x, y values within the containing view

Comment: how about making use of a `UICollectionVIewFlowLayout` https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/UsingtheFlowLayout/UsingtheFlowLayout.html

Comment: Depending on the versions of iOS you need to support, and the performance needs of your view, you might set up your tableview prototype cell to have a stack view, into which you can insert the buttons at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment of @Palpatim inspired to do it like the following:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell: UITableViewCell?

    if let item: TagItem = items[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] as? TagItem {
        if (item.tags.count > 0) {
            // show all tags as a Chip

            cell = TableViewCell()
            cell?.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            var hStackView          = UIStackView()
            hStackView.axis         = .horizontal
            hStackView.spacing      = 8
            hStackView.alignment    = .fill
            hStackView.distribution = .fill

            let vStackView          = UIStackView()
            vStackView.axis         = .vertical
            vStackView.spacing      = 8
            vStackView.alignment    = .top

            var tagsWidth: CGFloat = 0
            for tag in item.tags {
                let chip = ChipButton()
                chip.title  = tag.text
                chip.sizeToFit()

                if (tagsWidth + chip.bounds.width < (cell?.bounds.width)!) {
                    tagsWidth += chip.bounds.width
                    hStackView.addArrangedSubview(chip)
                }
                else {
                    vStackView.addArrangedSubview(hStackView)
                    tagsWidth = chip.bounds.width
                    hStackView = UIStackView()
                    hStackView.axis         = .horizontal
                    hStackView.spacing      = 8
                    hStackView.alignment    = .fill
                    hStackView.distribution = .fill
                    hStackView.addArrangedSubview(chip)
                }
            }

            vStackView.addArrangedSubview(hStackView)

            cell!.layout(vStackView).edges(left: 16, right: 16).centerVertically()

            return cell!
        }
        else {
            cell = TableViewCell(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.bounds.width, height: 40))
            // show a label 
            let infoLabel = UILabel()
            infoLabel.text          = "no tags"

            cell!.layout(infoLabel).centerVertically().edges(left: 16)

            return cell!
        }
    }

    cell = TableViewCell()
    return cell!
}
```

and the result is:

[image]